# is this a valid git fork use-case?

Tags: git, github

There's a github repo I'd like to fork (let's call it 'upstream') and add some tiny bits of functionality on top of it. I 'm not going to issue any pull requests for this functionality as it is too specific for my use-case. However, I want to receive updates from 'upstream', and to be able, should I stumble upon an bug, to issue a pull request.

There's the rub though: I understand that [I should keep my fork clean](http://blog.evan.pro/keeping-a-clean-github-fork-part-1), meaning all work should be done in branches. I believe this is both to enable pull requests for a specific branch and to allow me to frequently update my master branch from the 'upstream'.

How then am I going to make independent progress in my forked repository in the limited functionality I wish to add?

- if my functionality is added in the master branch of my forked repo then I violate the "keep the fork master branch clean" guideline
- if my functionality is added in a branch (for which I will never issue a pull request) then my master will never arrive at the state I want it to be (which is the 'upstream' master plus a thin layer of additional functionality that's specific to my use case as I said).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your `master` mirroring the upstream `master`, and do your work on a separate branch. Merge `master` into your branch regularly, so that the branch you're on represents "upstream's latest stuff, plus all my changes".

Comment: So if I read you right I would have a "pseudo-master" branch. That's fine. Now, if I want to fix a bug in 'upstream' with a pull request I'll create a branch off the "master", and then merge it into my "pseudo-master"? Wouldn't that eventually lead to a conflict when he does pull in my bug fix as by that time I would already have merged it into my own "pseudo-master"?? Sadly, inability to fork my own github repos prevents me from experimenting ...

Comment: You're imbuing too much magic into forks. A fork is just another set of branches - you can easily create extra branches of your own code, and pretend some of them are owned by you and some by upstream, if you want to play around and see what happens.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus And no, there will be no conflict. He'll accept your pull request by merging your feature branch in; then you'll merge that into your `master` branch; and you'll finally merge that into your `working` branch. git is smart, and understands the history graph: there won't be any merge conflicts that don't need to exist. In this case, the common ancestor should mean the merge is a no-op, or close enough.

Comment: Aren't the semantics of "his latest stuff, plus all my changes" better indicated by **rebasing** by branch on master instead of *merging* master into my branch? It's not a rhetorical question, I am really asking.

Comment: Either is fine. I would merge, but I don't think there's anything obviously wrong with rebasing. You might end up having to resolve the same conflict multiple times if you rebase? I don't *think* so, but I also don't see any clear gain to rebasing.